# Why is perlin noise generating flat terrain in Unity?

Tags: unity, procedural-generation, unityscript, perlin-noise

I am trying to generate terrain using perlin noise however the terrain being generated is a plateau. Here is the code that I'm using:

```
var xlength = 65.0;
var ylength = 65.0;
var scale = 4.1f;
var heights = new float[xlength, ylength];
function Start () {
    for (var i = 0; i < xlength; i++)
        for (var j = 0; j < ylength;j++)
            heights[i,j] = Mathf.PerlinNoise(Time.time * i / xlength * scale/1000,Time.time * j / ylength * scale/1000)*i*j;
    gameObject.GetComponent(Terrain).terrainData.SetHeights(0,0,heights);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want seamless 'chunks', then you should evenly sample between whole integers.

```
 heights[i,j] = Mathf.PerlinNoise(i / xlength, j / ylength);
```

And resulting data must be between 0..1 (so don't scale it here).

> heights:  Array of heightmap samples to set (values range from 0 to 1,
>   array indexed as [y,x]).
>   **<sub>- [Unity Documentation: TerrainData.SetHeights](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TerrainData.SetHeights.html)</sub>**